# 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd5 in position 2912: invalid continuation byte Error when reading csv file in Python

Tags: python, csv, utf-8

I am cycling through the rows of a csv file, but come across this error when looping through the rows:
`'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd5 in position 2912: invalid continuation byte`

I'm just trying to get the row count for the file with this function:

```
def count_lines(filename):
    row_stored = ""
    try:
        with open(filename) as csvfile:
            data_reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
            next(data_reader)
            count = 0
            for index, row in enumerate(data_reader):
                if index == 1220119:
                    print(row)
                row_stored = row
                count += 1
            return count
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'There was a problem with your request: {e}\n', row_stored)
        return False
```

The row above the erroring row looks like this:

```
['817949019495', 'QMMZN1300568', '4/28/2017', 'Digital Revenue', 'Track', 'Download Europe', 'GB', 'Amazon International - UK', '', '2', '1.2126506333579932', '109926407', '2/28/2017']
```

And the row that throws the error looks like this:

```
['817949019495', 'QMMZN1300568', '4/28/2017', 'Digital Revenue', 'Track', 'Download Europe', 'GB', 'Amazon International - UK', '', '2', '1.2126506333579932', '109926407', '2/28/2017']
```

I don't see any differences in the two. Is there something with the formatting of this particular row that I'm not seeing?

*Note: This csv file is 3.17 GB. Don't know if that's a contributing factor*

Comment: code `b'\xd5'.decode('latin1')` gives `Õ` and `b'\xd5'.decode('cp1250')` gives little different `Ő`, but `b'\xd5'.decode('utf-8')` raise error - so your data doesn't use `utf-8` but other encoding and you have to set correct encoding when you read it.

Comment: code should raise error when you read - so it raise before `row_stored = row` and your `print(... row_stored)` can display row which doesn't make problem - you should check next row in file to see what makes problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the encoding fixed this problem

```
with open(filename, encoding="ISO-8859-1") as csvfile:
```

Comment: Did it?  `ISO-8859-1` can decode anything, even if that isn't the correct encoding, so you may get corrupted characters.  I didn't see any non-ASCII characters in the row that you claim threw the error though.  Byte 0xd5 corresponds to the character `Õ` in ISO-8859-1.

Comment: Ya, surprisingly. Not sure what was causing the error still, but check out the Screenshot I took of the MySQL table I was populating. (Yes, it is a large table)

Comment: You have the exact offset in the file with the bad byte.  Do something like `print(open(file,'rb').read(2930)[:-50])` to see what is exactly around the offset 2912 error byte.  this reads the first 2930 bytes and prints the last 50.